Integrated webcam stopped working - Ubuntu 22.04
Since my last firmware update, my integrated webcam (despite being detected) is showing a blackscreen. I tried with Zoom client, Google Meet and Slack huddle. Same behavior on all.
Cheese is not responding when I try to launch it (I don't know if it's related).
I also tried a webcam test on https://webcamtests.com/, it says that my webcam is detected but the test shows a blackscreen.
Yes, my webcam is enabled in my BIOS settings.
v4l2-ctl --list-devices is outputting this:
Intel MIPI Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0

The permissions for this file (ls -l /dev/video0) are:
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Apr 12 13:33 /dev/video0

Yes, my user is in the video group.
lsusb is outputting this:
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:63cc Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 005: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0bda:0413 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 006 Device 006: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0bda:0487 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 413c:b06e Dell Computer Corp. Dell dock
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 413c:b06f Dell Computer Corp. Dell dock
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 0bda:5413 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 005 Device 010: ID 2109:8817 VIA Labs, Inc. PD3.0 USB-C Device     
Bus 005 Device 009: ID 1395:0291 Sennheiser Communications EPOS IMPACT 60
Bus 005 Device 008: ID 046d:c093 Logitech, Inc. Advanced Corded Mouse M500s
Bus 005 Device 007: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bda:5487 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

I think my webcam is Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bda:5487 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock.
lspci is outputting this:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device a706
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a70d
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device a7a0 (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a71d
00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device a75d
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a74d
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a72f
00:07.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a71f
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device a74f
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a77d (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a71e
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a76d
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 51fc (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 51f1 (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 51e3 (rev 01)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b3 (rev 01)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH UART #0 (rev 01)
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ab (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 519d (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 25bc (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2291 (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
2d:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
2e:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
2e:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
2f:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
57:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

xinput --list is outputting this:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Advanced Corded Mouse M500s      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Advanced Corded Mouse M500s Keyboard id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VEN_27C6:00 27C6:0F60 Mouse               id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VEN_27C6:00 27C6:0F60 Touchpad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=25   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard System Control      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ sof-soundwire Headset Jack                id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Privacy Driver                       id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=24   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Advanced Corded Mouse M500s Keyboard id=26   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sennheiser EPOS IMPACT 60 Consumer Control    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sennheiser EPOS IMPACT 60                 id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]

I found no fruitful solution online. I tried resetting my BIOS settings to default, I tried reinstalling gstreamer1.0-icamera, I tried reinstalling v4l2-ctl. All my apt packages are up to date. All my snaps are up to date.
Thanks in advance for your help!

I found a working solution:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-engineers/oem-projects-meta
sudo apt install oem-somerville-tentacool-meta
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo systemctl poweroff

Boot back your computer and it should work.
This solution doesn't fix the Cheese problem though. In order for Cheese to work, I had to launch it in terminal by specifying the device:
sudo cheese -d "Intel MIPI Camera"

Where "Intel MIPI Camera" is the device associated to your /dev/video0 file when you run v4l2-ctl --list-devices
